# Meaning of alternation in definition of wedge product

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, differential-forms

Spivak defines the wedge product as

$\omega \wedge \nu = \frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!} \text{Alt}(\omega \otimes \nu)$

and I have been running into some conceptual issues here. The alternation is defined as

$\text{Alt}(T)(v_1, \dots , v_n) = \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma \in S} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot T(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots , v_{\sigma(n)})$

which seems to me to be some type of weighted average of the possible values of T (which is multilinear). I am just failing to see how this plays into the definition of the wedge product. Reading some other books, it seems like the wedge product helps to form operators from a k-dimensional space to $R$. I'm just not seeing the motivation for this specific definition of the product, and it is really making it difficult to understand differential forms.

Any advice here or in general?

Comment: The formula you've written for Alt($T$) makes no sense. The left-hand side is a tensor; the right-hand side is a real number, because you're evaluating $T$ at $v_{\sigma(1)}$, $\ldots$, $v_{\sigma(n)}$. What you meant to write is Alt($T$)($v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(n)}$).

Comment: Thanks, I somehow forgot that when I was typing. I'll edit the parent

Comment: Some intuition: the point of the alternating condition is that it detects linear dependencies. This means e.g. that for linear functionals $\omega$ and $\nu$, $\omega\wedge\nu$ will evaluate to 0 on a pair of vectors precisely when one is a multiple of the other. (The idea is general: an alternating tensor will evaluate to 0 on an $n$-tuple of vectors precisely when they are linearly dependent.) This makes such tensors extremely useful for "algebraicizing" geometry. A very good toy example is here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1684/why-is-the-exterior-algebra-so-ubiquitous/36817#36817

Comment: The point is that the wedge product should yield an antisymmetric tensor, and $\operatorname{Alt}(T)$ is antisymmetric for any tensor $T$. (Note that if $T$ is itself antisymmetric, then $\operatorname{Alt}(T) = T$, so we can think of $\operatorname{Alt}$ as a projection $\bigotimes^k V \to \bigwedge^k V$.)

Comment: Also, in the formula for $\operatorname{Alt}$, the factorial expression should be $n!$, not $k!$.

Comment: More to the point in Travis's comment, in your definition of Alt,  if $T$ is a $k$-tensor, then you should be evaluating on $k$ vectors, and $\sigma$ should live in $S_k$. Alternatively, if $T$ is an $n$-tensor, then $\sigma\in S_n$ and there should be a factor of $1/n!$.